How to Simulate a Multilevel Predictor Variable with Both L1 and L2 Variance Components?
I'm working on simulating multilevel data where I have a predictor variable measured at Level 1 (L1), which has both L1 and L2 variance components. For example, I want to simulate a socio-economic status (SES) variable measured at the individual level within school classes. In a multilevel model, I would typically use group-mean centering to separate the within-group (L1) and between-group (L2) variance of this predictor.
Specifically, I’m interested in simulating an L1 predictor (e.g., individual SES) along with its group-mean centered counterpart to capture the group-level (L2) variance. My goal is to create data that:
Reflects both within-group and between-group variability for SES.
Allows me to use multilevel modeling approaches to disentangle these variance components, similar to how group-mean centering works in real data.
My questions are:
How would I approach simulating such an L1 predictor variable with both L1 and L2 variance?
What steps should I follow to generate the group-mean centered version at L2?
Here is a great post dwelling on a similar matter.
It is not hard to simulate a L1 predictor and then creating a centre version of it on L2. However, in this approach L1 has no true L2 variance:
# Define simulation parameters
n_groups <- 50       # Number of groups (Level 2)
n_individuals <- 10  # Number of individuals per group (Level 1)
total_n <- n_groups * n_individuals

# Define variances
between_var <- 1     # Between-group variance
within_var <- 0.5    # Within-group variance

# Simulate random intercepts for each group (Level 2 random effect)
group_effect <- rnorm(n_groups, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(between_var))

# Create a data frame to store the simulated data
data <- data.frame(
  group_id = rep(1:n_groups, each = n_individuals),
  individual_id = 1:total_n
)

# Generate Level 1 predictor `x1ij` with both within and between-group variability
data$x1ij <- group_effect[data$group_id] + rnorm(total_n, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(within_var))

# Compute the group mean for `x1ij` (Level 2 component)
data$x1j_mean <- ave(data$x1ij, data$group_id, FUN = mean)

# Create group-mean centered version of `x1ij`
data$x1ij_centered <- data$x1ij - data$x1j_mean

# Display the first few rows of the dataset
head(data)
```


This is a great question (+1). I have thought about these issues quite a bit and your question inspired me to play around with some simulated data. Because I am much more facile in Stata than R, I used Stata to do the simulation, but the general idea should work in any software. And if you end up implementing it in R, please post back with your updated code.
TL:DR
The key thing you have to do is to add both between- and within-group variance to the predictor -x in my code below. This is exactly the same process you go through when creating the outcome - y, below. If you want to construct y so that both the within- and between parts of x influence it, you need to alter how you construct y.
The following code shows my process and checks the results.
clear *
version 18
set seed 113054
set obs 30              // N of L2 units (classrooms)
gen class = _n
gen u_i = rnormal(0,3)  // random y intercept (SD=3; variance=9)
gen x_i = rnormal(0,2)  // random x intercept (SD = 2, variance = 4)

*Stata uses expand to create new observations (students) for each unique row
expand 15               // 30 (classes) * 15 (students/class) = 450 observations
bysort class: gen stuid = _n

*Generate residual errors (variance) for both y and x 
gen e_ij = rnormal(0,5)     // residual w/ mean 0, SD=5 (variance=25)
gen x_e_ij = rnormal(0, 3.5) // residual x_e_ij w/ mean 0, SD = 3.5 (variance = 12.25)

*Generate x w/ both it's between and within-group errors added 
gen x = x_i + x_e_ij 

*Generate y with an effect of x 
gen y = 70 + 1.5*x + u_i + e_ij     

*Initial model for y on x 
mixed y x || class:, reml stddev

Results generally match the simulation parameters:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   1.583078   .0686275    23.07   0.000      1.44857    1.717585
       _cons |   70.03036   .5199314   134.69   0.000     69.01132    71.04941
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Random-effects parameters  |   Estimate   Std. err.     [95% conf. interval]
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
class: Identity              |
                   sd(_cons) |   2.549075   .4181922      1.848152    3.515829
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
                sd(Residual) |   4.910492   .1696059      4.589073    5.254424
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

But what about that between group variance in x? Let's separate it out and re-run the model w/ x and the group mean of x as predictors.
bysort class: egen cmn_x = mean(x)
mixed y x cmn_x || class:, reml stddev 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   1.577422   .0710982    22.19   0.000     1.438072    1.716772
       cmn_x |   .0829808   .2761226     0.30   0.764    -.4582096    .6241713
       _cons |   70.04424   .5297397   132.22   0.000     69.00596    71.08251
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Random-effects parameters  |   Estimate   Std. err.     [95% conf. interval]
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
class: Identity              |
                   sd(_cons) |   2.596581    .430257      1.876535    3.592917
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
                sd(Residual) |   4.910855   .1696427      4.589367    5.254863
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

When we leave x uncentered in this model and add its group mean as a predictor, the coefficient for the group mean is the difference between the within and between effect of x on y. This reports that there is little to no difference between those two.
If we want there to be an effect, we need to add it to the data generation model for y. Here I generate y_new, which is exactly the same as y but with an additional component for cmn_x:
gen y_new = 70 + 1.5*x + .8*cmn_x + u_i + e_ij 
mixed y_new x cmn_x || class:, reml stddev
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       y_new | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   1.577422   .0710982    22.19   0.000     1.438072    1.716772
       cmn_x |   .8829808   .2761226     3.20   0.001     .3417904    1.424171
       _cons |   70.04424   .5297397   132.22   0.000     69.00596    71.08251
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Random-effects parameters  |   Estimate   Std. err.     [95% conf. interval]
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
class: Identity              |
                   sd(_cons) |   2.596582    .430257      1.876535    3.592917
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
                sd(Residual) |   4.910855   .1696427      4.589367    5.254863
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

That is what we wanted. Results match what we put in the data generation for y_new. Note that we can get the group level effect of x on y_new by adding the coefficients of x and cmn_x:
lincom x + cmn_x

 ( 1)  [y_new]x + [y_new]cmn_x = 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       y_new | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         (1) |   2.460403   .2668122     9.22   0.000     1.937461    2.983345
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

